# WPF Official Ribbon Control Themes

Tags: wpf, themes, ribbon

Can you help me please finding themes for the Microsoft Ribbon for WPF October 2010 release?
I want to change the default blue theme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no themes for the Microsoft Ribbon for WPF October release, you have to come up with your own styles.

Answer (score 3):

[This is the best Fluent Ribbon control I know for WPF](http://fluent.codeplex.com/)

Supports everything (and re-styling, black/blue/silver are included so far)

Comment: This control is great (I've used it), but I don't think he's asking for an alternative.